# how do I resize a SKShapeNode?

Tags: swift

I have initialised a SKShapeNode object which is rectangular in shape, how do I reduce the width of this object by a fixed value?

I have this so far:

```
    var health_bar = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))
    health_bar.name = "health_bar_name"
    health_bar.fillColor = SKColor.green
    health_bar.position = CGPoint(x: 70, y: 400)
    scene.addChild(health_bar)
```

I want to reduce the width of the rectangle by say, 25. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the width dimension of the node using health_bar.scale().  It takes a SCNVector3.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408050-scale)

Comment: could you please give me an example? Cause it's still not resizing